# browser freezes with this js code, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a javascript code. But when I try to execute it on a browser(firefox&chrome) browser just freezes and have to force it to quit. I am trying to generate 5 of this image in random places of leftSide. Here's the code, what's wrong here?

```
<html><head>
<title></title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
img {
    position: absolute;}
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;}

#rightSide {
    left: 500px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;}
</style>
    <script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
      function generateFaces() {
      while (numberOfFaces) {
      var smileFace = document.createElement("img");
      var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
      smileFace.src = "smile.png";
      smileFace.style.top = random_number + "px";
      smileFace.style.left = random_number + "px";
      document.getElementById('leftSide').appendChild(smileFace);}}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="generateFaces()">
<h2>Matching Game</h2>
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the left.</p>
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"></div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `while (numberOfFaces) { code not changing numberOfFaces }`...

Comment: Because your `numberOfFaces` doesn't decrement in `while` loop

Comment: Infinite loop. Decrement or put any condition for `numberOfFaces`

Comment: `while (numberOfFaces--) {`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Do you want to trigger an overflow ? There's none in JS.

Comment: Why use loops before learn how it works? (facepalm).

Comment: Irrelevant, but proper code formatting really helps you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define `numberOfFaces` as 5, and then start a `while` loop which checks if that variable has a *truthy* value - anything above 0 is truthy. That variable will never change though, resulting in an infinite loop.

You need to decrement it somewhere inside the loop using `numberOfFaces--;` or similar. Maybe like this:

```
<script>
    var numberOfFaces = 5;
    function generateFaces() {
      while (numberOfFaces) {
        var smileFace = document.createElement("img");
        var random_number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        smileFace.src = "smile.png";
        smileFace.style.top = random_number + "px";
        smileFace.style.left = random_number + "px";
        document.getElementById('leftSide').appendChild(smileFace);
        numberOfFaces--;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Maybe do a tutorial on `while` loops to help understand this more: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_while_loop.htm

**Note:** *Above while loop will stop when `numberOfFaces` becomes `0`. In JS, 0 is falsy*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for kindly helping and the link. So a loop only stops when it reaches 0, which is `false`. As long as it's `true` (above 0) and never reaches 0, it's infinite. Right?

Comment: In your case, yes - you only wrote `while(numberOfFaces)` which checks if numberOfFaces is truthy or not. If you wanted it to be a certain value, you could do `while(numberOfFaces > 4)` for example

Answer (score 0):

This while loop of yours is an infinite one; `numberOfFaces` is  constantly 5, which is a truthy value. Try to change it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {
  // never stops
  // 5 is truthy value
}
```

You are looking for this:

```
for(var i=numberOfFaces; 0 < i; i--){
  // your iteration code
}
```